# Running a different method each time through a loop

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement, case

My goal is to cut down on code by running this code through a loop

```
each_score = ones(dice_values);
total_score += each_score;
end_scores += String.valueOf(each_score) + " ";
```

followed by

```
each_score = twos(dice_values);
total_score += each_score;
end_scores += String.valueOf(each_score) + " ";
```

The only difference being the method in line one.  I don't know of a way to do anything like this through something like a for loop and would rather not copy paste that code 13 times.  (I'm also hoping for something more efficient than a switch case if that were possible)

```
private static int ones(int[] dice_values) {
    int ones = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if(dice_values[i] == 1)
            ones++;     
    return ones;
}

private static int fours(int[] dice_values) {
    int fours = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if(dice_values[i] == 4)
            fours++;        
    return (fours * 4);
}


private static int five_of_kind(int[] dice_values) {
    int five_kind = 0;
    int[] five_of = new int[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        five_of[dice_values[i] - 1]++;

    if(Arrays.asList(five_of).contains(5))
        five_kind = 50;
    return five_kind;
}
```

This is a sample of the methods.  I'm solving a simple problem called Yahtzee.  Given a set of 13 rolls of 5 dice, find the total score of all the rolls and the total of each type of point scored (the points being "one's: how many ones"  or "five of a kind" as examples).

Comment: what is the purpose of ones(), twos(), etc methods?  if they serve a similar purpose, you could create a generic function with a parameter 1, 2, etc.

Comment: I could combine the first 6 of the methods doing that, but there are others (4 of a kind, short straight, long straight, full house, etc) that I couldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use reflection for this scenario,

```
string[] methodNames = new string{}["ones","twos",....];
for(string method : methodNames)
{
    Method method = this.getClass().getMethod(dice_values.getClass());
    each_score = method.Invoke(this,dice_values);
    total_score += each_score;
    end_scores += String.valueOf(each_score) + " ";
}
```

Comment: Ah, I really like this solution, but unfortunately I was building this all from one class....but this is intriguing enough that I think I'll convert it over so my methods aren't static.

Comment: Update:  Using this method I'm getting an error at getMethod:                           The method getMethod(String, Class<?>...) in the type Class<capture#1-of ? extends ScoreGenerator> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#2-of ? extends int[]>)                      ...................however, adding a name in getMethod to match the examples gets rid of the error....will continue work on it

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something (and without a `switch`), you could build an array of `int` scores and iterate that array of `scores`. That is something like

```
int [] scores = new int[] {
        ones(dice_values), twos(dice_values), threes(dice_values), 
        fours(dice_values), fives(dice_values), sixes(dice_values), 
        sevens(dice_values), eights(dice_values), nines(dice_values),
        tens(dice_values), elevens(dice_values), twelves(dice_values),
        thirteens(dice_values)
};
for (int each_score : scores) {
    total_score += each_score;
    end_scores += String.valueOf(each_score) + " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
    switch(i) {
        case 1:
            each_score = ones(dice_values);
        break;

        case 2:
            each_score = twos(dice_values);
        break;

        ...

    }
    total_score += each_score;
    end_scores += String.valueOf(each_score) + " ";
}
```